# Error while training a Faster R-CNN object detection model: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor to a numpy array

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn, roboflow

I was trying to train an object detection model using the Roboflow Google Colab notebook on the link below. Until Tuesday it was working properly to me but since that day, is not working any more, and I have not made any change to the code or the libraries or GitHub repositories used.

It displays the following error when I run the cell below: “NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (cond_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array.”

```
!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py
–pipeline_config_path={pipeline_fname}
–model_dir={model_dir}
–alsologtostderr
–num_train_steps={num_steps}
–num_eval_steps={num_eval_steps}
```

Does anyone know what has happened or how can I solve it to keep training my model?

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U3fkRu6-hwjk7wWIpg-iylL2u5T9t7rr#scrollTo=yhzxsJb3dpWq

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try again by downgrading `numpy` to `1.19.5` or 
`pip install -U numpy==1.18.5`.